# Sum the rows of a pandas dataframe grouping by the dates with the same year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. lets call it `df`:

```
|Account  |Type   |Date        | Per   | Value|
-----------------------------------------------
|A        |FC     |31/03/2019  |3M     |a     |
|A        |FC     |30/06/2019  |3M     |b     |
|A        |FC     |30/09/2019  |3M     |c     |
|A        |FC     |31/12/2019  |3M     |d     |
|B        |P&G    |31/03/2019  |3M     |e     |
|B        |P&G    |30/06/2019  |3M     |f     |
|B        |P&G    |30/09/2019  |3M     |g     |
|B        |P&G    |31/12/2019  |3M     |h     |
```

Where a,bc,d,e,f,g,h are numerical values.For each element of the account column I need to sum up the values of the value column that are in the same year, according to the date column, getting something like this:

```
|Account  |Type   |Date        | Per   | Value  |
-------------------------------------------------
|A        |FC     |31/12/2019  |3M     |a+b+c+d |
|B        |P&G    |30/12/2019  |3M     |e+f+g+h |
```

Where the value of the date column of the resulting dataframe corresponds to the last period that was added.

I tried the next code:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Date').sum().reset_index())
```

And I get the next dataframe:

```
    Date    Value
0   2016    294590.0158
1   2017    235216.0481
2   2018    326280.1496
3   2019    152482.2480
```

But clearly this is not what i was looking for.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: use `d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns} ; d['Value'] = 'sum' ; df.groupby(['Account', pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.year], as_index=False).agg(d)`

Comment: Using pivot and your answer I was able to get to what I need. Can you explain me why did you use this part of the code: d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns}?

Comment: To aggregate with the first value by default for all columns, except for Value.

Comment: Perfect! Thamks! And what if I don't want to keep the sum pf the numeric values, but the last one? I mean: instead of have a+b+d+d in the Value column I need to have only d; and instead of e+f+g+h i only need to have h